# Getting invalid credentials even the credentials are registered in database in django login form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having a registration,login and dashboard the registration form is successfully registering and the users are storing in the custom user model now after registering the page will go to login now button if user clicks it will redirect to login page in login page I am having a username and password field and it should authenticate with the registered users and if the credentials are valid the dashboard page should come but here the problem after registration when I go to login page and try to login with the credentials which are registered I am getting message as invalid credentials.

```
My views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages, auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from contacts.models import Contact
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages,auth
from account.forms import UserForm
from account.forms import UserRequirementForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def register(request):
  return render(request, 'account/register.html',);
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if there is a post request in the form
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST) #first of all it is a user_form will be posted details present in the user_form
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(data=request.POST)# after posting the details of the user_form post the details
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
         # if user_form & user_requirement form is valid
         User = user_form.save()#if form is valid save
         user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
         # Set user
         user_requirement.user = User
         user_requirement.save()
         user_requirement_form.save_m2m()
         messages.success(request,('Project saved successfully'))
         return render(request,'account/home1.html')
        else:
          messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors above')
    else:  
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()
    return render(request,'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'requirements_form': user_requirement_form})

def login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
      messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials')
      return redirect('login')
  else:
    return render(request, 'account/login.html')

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html',);
```

URLS.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path


from . import views
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register,name='register'),
    path('user_register/', views.user_register, name='user_register'),
    path('login/', views.login,name='login'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
]
```

login.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password2">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
        </form>
```

Forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

    def clean_email(self):
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email as a username.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')
class UserRequirementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_Requirement
        fields=('room','goal','design','furniture')
        error_messages = {
            'room': {
                'required': "Please select any of the room in the first step",
            },
            'goal': {
                'required': "Please select any of the goals in the second step",
            },
            'design': {
                'required': "Please select any of the design in the forth step",
            },
            'furniture': {
                'required': "Please select any of the furniture in the third step",
            },
        }
```

Comment: add your code of `UserForm`.

Comment: @Nalin I added the UserForm

Comment: try to add `User.set_password(request.POST['password']` then `User.save()` after `User = user_form.save()`

Comment: You mean in views @nalin

Comment: yes, in views, after you are calling `User = user_form.save()`, put those 2 lines after that.

Comment: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
this error is coming after login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `user.set_password()` method to save password in hashed format.

```py
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # if there is a post request in the form
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST) #first of all it is a user_form will be posted details present in the user_form
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm(data=request.POST)# after posting the details of the user_form post the details
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_requirement_form.is_valid():
         # if user_form & user_requirement form is valid
         User = user_form.save()#if form is valid save

         # Add these 2 lines.
         User.set_password(request.POST['password'])
         User.save()

         user_requirement = user_requirement_form.save(commit=False)
         # Set user
         user_requirement.user = User
         user_requirement.save()
         user_requirement_form.save_m2m()
         messages.success(request,('Project saved successfully'))
         return render(request,'account/home1.html')
        else:
          messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors above')
    else:  
        user_form = UserForm()
        user_requirement_form = UserRequirementForm()
    return render(request,'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'requirements_form': user_requirement_form})
```

Comment: with your code login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given this error is coming after login getting this error @Nalin

Comment: I think that's because of name conflict, your login function`def login(request):` and `login(request, user)` has same name. change `def login(request):` to `def login_view(request):`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more efficient way of implementation, instead of writing custom login method.
Just make changes in your urls.py and login.html

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [ 
path('register/', views.register,name='register'),
path('user_register/', views.user_register, name='user_register'),
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html'),name="login"),
path('dashboard/', views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
]
```

**login.html**

```
 <form style="max-width: 250px; margin: auto;" method='POST'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   <fieldset>
      **{{form}}**
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Login</button>
    </div>

   </fieldset>
</form>
```

you no need to write any authentication and credential validation steps in views.py. **django.contrib.auth.LoginView** will takecare of all invalid credentials etc.
It decreases your effort of mapping form data to model form and writing more steps in.
The above **loginview** will redirect to blank url('/').
Please add the below lines in **views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard')
    return render(request,'account/home.html',{})
```

Add url path to **urls.py** where project's **settings.py** is present.

**/urls.py**

```
from account import views as views # add app/dir name in place of account where your views.py present
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.home,name="home"),
]
```

add **home.html**

```
<a href="{%url 'login'%}">Login here</a>
```

**Explaination**

When your login is successful you will be redirected to **home url** the **def home** in views.py is called you will be checking the user is authenticated or not. If authenticated you will redirect to dashboard

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

else if you try to access home page without authentication you will be having home page with **login link.**