# Cannot login after a user activate account

Tags: python, django, django-views

Working on a django project, successfully done the registration, login, logout and activate views, the registration is working because a user get a link sent to their email after they signup but I'm having errors saying invalid credentials when I try to login with that created account, I could login with the admin account though. Here is the codes

register view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split('@')[0]
            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, password=password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()
            
             # Create a user profile
            profile = UserProfile()
            profile.user_id = user.id
            profile.profile_picture = 'default/default.png'
            profile.save()
           
            
            #user activation
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = "WElcome to ECO, Please activate your account"
            message = render_to_string('ecousers/account_verification_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain':current_site,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = email
            send_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            send_email.send()
            # messages.success(request, "Account created successfully")
            return redirect('/accounts/login/?command=verification&email='+email)
    else:
        
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'ecousers/register.html', context)
```

login and activate views

```
def login(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid login credentials")
            return redirect('ecousers:login')
    return render(request, 'ecousers/login.html')

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
        user = Account._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Account.DoesNotExist):
        user =None
    
    if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Congratulations!! Your account is activated')
        return redirect('ecousers:login')
        
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid activation link')
        return redirect('ecousers:register')
```

Please what could be the issue, I cannot login after account has been activated

Comment: Hopefully this thread answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59763653/getting-invalid-credentials-even-the-credentials-are-registered-in-database-in-d

Comment: I tried it now I'm getting a new error, please I would really appreciate if you can explain more here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you able to login with that new acc in the admin panel? and what is the Error?

Comment: No I just noticed that the admin can't login to the main site but can only login to the admin panel. Same issue with a user after account has been activated.